# How to get extended locale information with Windows CRT API

Tags: c, windows, locale

I am working on a personal prooject in which I need to obtain full locale formatting information from a C locale.

I cannot simply use `localeconv` or `localeconv_l` since `lconv` does not provide all formatting information needed. To solve this on *NIX there are `nl_langinfo` and `nl_langinfo_l` functions, however they are not present on Windows.

What ways are there to obtain locale formatting information on Windows?

Comment: `nl_langinfo()` availability is not an OS one like "*NIX" vs. "Windows", but a compiler one.  A windows machine may use `gcc` and have `nl_langinfo()`.  Better to specify the _compilers_ of interest.

Answer (score 0):

start with: [GetUserDefaultUILanguage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getuserdefaultuilanguage)

Similar and related APIs include:

[GetUserDefaultLocaleName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getuserdefaultlocalename)

[GetUserDefaultLCID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getuserdefaultlcid)

[GetUserDefaultLangID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getuserdefaultlangid)

Answer (score 0):

The Perl 5 open source C language code contains an emulation of nl_langinfo(), for Windows and other platforms that lack it.  You can steal the code, though it is complicated by trying to work on a bunch of different platforms with a bunch of different configurations

A few fields aren't implemented such as the Japanese emperor era names.  But anything in common use is available.

Start with this file: https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/locale.c

The code continues to evolve